# Expected primary-expression before 'const'

Tags: arduino

I am trying to send one UDP packet but get stuck on concatenate between different data type and don't know how to solve it.

The code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

WiFiUDP Udp;
const char* UdpIPaddress  = "192.168.0.240";
unsigned int UdpPort = 4210;  

const char* Udpmessage  = "Message";
int a=0;
float Temp=29.25;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (115200); 
}

void loop() {
  if(a==0){
    a = a + 1;
    const char* sendmessage = const char*(a) + "=" + const char*(Temp) + "=" + Udpmessage;
    UdpSend(sendmessage, UdpIPaddress, UdpPort);
  }
}


void UdpSend(const char* message, const char * ipaddress, int port){
      Serial.println("Send message: ");
      Udp.beginPacket(ipaddress, port);
      Udp.write(message);
      Udp.endPacket();
}
```

Arduino IDE compiler error: *expected primary-expression before 'const'*

Please help...

Comment: in your previous question you were advised to use String. it is a class with overloaded operators to concatenate with different data types. you can't do the same with char arrays (or pointers to not allocated arrays as you do). use String or learn how to use C strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate char, int, long, and String in Arduino? (SOLVED)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53914835/how-to-concatenate-char-int-long-and-string-in-arduino-solved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer of my own question:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

WiFiUDP Udp;
const char* UdpIPaddress = "192.168.0.240";
unsigned int UdpPort = 4210; 
char buf[40];

const char* Udpmessage = "Message";
int a=0;
float Temp=29.25;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin (115200);
}

void loop() {
 if(a==0){    
   a = a + 1;
   sprintf(buf, "%d=%f=%s", a,Temp, Udpmessage);
   UdpSend(buf, UdpIPaddress, UdpPort);
 }
}

void UdpSend(const char* message, const char * ipaddress, int port){
     Serial.println("Send message: ");
     Udp.beginPacket(ipaddress, port);
     Udp.write(message);
     Udp.endPacket();
}
```

Works perfectly :) :) :)